# Return matched documents from the array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am currently trying to query a array in mongodb, I want to look for all the fields that have the id: "`ZhU76Ta`" in them, but the array to search is barryed in a other doc, so my query looks something like this: `{"punishdata.Entrys.0.id": "ZhU76Ta"}` but this only query the first doc in the array, I tryed something like this `{"punishdata.Entrys.*.id": "ZhU76Ta" }` but this also does not work, dose anybody know how to do this?

```
Document structure:
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b212e540a975a231c85419c"),
"name" : "Starmixcraft",
"punishdata" : {
    "Entrys" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "ZhU76Ta",
            "end" : NumberLong(-2),
            "start" : NumberLong(1528901227837),
            "time" : NumberLong(-2)
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: post your sample collection please

Comment: Added sampe collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$filter aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)  here which simply eliminates the unmatched documents from the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "punishdata.Entrys": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$punishdata.Entrys",
          "as": "entry",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$entry.id",
              "ZhU76Ta"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
db.collectionName.find({"punishdata.Entrys.id": "ZhU76Ta" })
```

Comment: That returns only the 0 entry,i want to get all entrys in the array thet matsch the quarry

Comment: do you have more values with the same id ZhU76Ta ?

Comment: @NetherGames-de the current answer is correct. I'm sure you are making something wrong...

Comment: @Serdar yes there are more values in the data thet have the id ZhU76Ta, and i want to get all of them

Comment: @NetherGames-de then try this: db.collectionName.find({"punishdata.Entrys.id": {$all:["ZhU76Ta"] }})